# Xamarin Android - How to sign in Google Play Services?

Tags: xamarin.android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-games

I am trying to add Google Play Services to my Xamarin Android app.

I am using Play Games Services v2 SDK and trying to follow [this tutorial from the Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/games/pgs/android/android-signin).

The Java code for signing in would be that:

```
GamesSignInClient gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(getActivity());

gamesSignInClient.isAuthenticated().addOnCompleteListener(isAuthenticatedTask -> {
  boolean isAuthenticated =
    (isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful() &&
     isAuthenticatedTask.getResult().isAuthenticated());

  if (isAuthenticated) {
    // Continue with Play Games Services
  } else {
    // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a
    // login button to ask  players to sign-in. Clicking it should
    // call GamesSignInClient.signIn().
  }
});
```

How can I translate it to C#?
Anyone can help me please?

This is my best attempt, but I am getting an exception on SetJniIdentityHashCode method not implemented.

```
using Android.Gms.Games;
using Android.Gms.Tasks;

// ...

PlayGamesSdk.Initialize(this);
IGamesSignInClient gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.GetGamesSignInClient(this);
gamesSignInClient.IsAuthenticated().AddOnCompleteListener(
    new OnCompleteListener()
);

// ...

public class OnCompleteListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener
{
    public void Disposed()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void DisposeUnlessReferenced()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Finalized()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnComplete(Task task)
    {
        //var isAuthenticated =
        //      (task.IsSuccessful && 
        //      ((????)task.Result).isAuthenticated())

        //if (isAuthenticated)
        //{
        //    // Continue with Play Games Services
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a
        //    // login button to ask  players to sign-in. Clicking it should
        //    // call GamesSignInClient.signIn().
        //}
    }

    public void SetJniIdentityHashCode(int value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SetJniManagedPeerState(JniManagedPeerStates value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void SetPeerReference(JniObjectReference reference)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check this package [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base).

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT I have this package already installed, but can't find a proper way to check if the user is authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the authentication result in the following way, probably was just using the wrong references.

```
public class TaskCompleteListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener
{
    public void OnComplete(Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task)
    {
        var isAuthenticated = task.IsSuccessful &&
            ((AuthenticationResult)task.Result).IsAuthenticated;

        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            // Continue with Play Games Services
        }
        else
        {
            // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a
            // login button to ask  players to sign-in. Clicking it should
            // call GamesSignInClient.signIn().
        }
    }
}
```